# Having trouble filtering folder list array

Tags: powershell

I have a list of folder names, it is over a million lines long but it looks like this...

```
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009991\BILLS\2018                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009993\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009993\BILLS\2014                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009993\BILLS\2015                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009993\BILLS\2016                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009995\BILLS                                                                                                                    
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009995\BILLS\2014                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009995\BILLS\2015                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009996\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009996\BILLS\2014                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009996\BILLS\2015                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009996\BILLS\2016                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009996\BILLS\2017                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10009996\BILLS\2018                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS                                                                                                                 
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS\2013                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS\2015                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS\2016                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS\2017                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS\2018                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\BILLS\2013                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\BILLS\2015                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\BILLS\2016                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\BILLS\2017                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010009\10009                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010009\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010009\10009\BILLS                                                                                                                 
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010011\10011                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010011\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010011\10011\BILLS                                                                                                                 
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\10013                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\10013\BILLS                                                                                                                 
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\10013\BILLS\2015                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\10013\BILLS\2016                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\10013\BILLS\2017                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\10013\BILLS\2018                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\BILLS\2015                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\BILLS\2016                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010013\BILLS\2017                                                                                                                  
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\10014                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\BILLS                                                                                                                       
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\10014\BILLS                                                                                                                 
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\10014\BILLS\2015                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\10014\BILLS\2016                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\10014\BILLS\2017                                                                                                            
\\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010014\BILLS\2015
```

Basically, I'm looking for the handful of customers IDs where there is not a BILLS folder following the 8 digit account number.

So it should return this line for example:

```
\HOSTNAME\c$\Docs\PROD\10010006\10006\BILLS
```

I realize there will be many duplicates. Ultimately I just want a list of the accounts where the old account number subfolder is present. This is what i have so far and it is not working. It just prints out the whole list.

```
$list = Get-Content "sample.txt"
foreach ($i in $list){
    $parts = $i -split '\\'
    if ($parts[7] -notlike '%Bills%'){
        Write-Host $parts
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the ones that say bill in it or are you trying to get the ones that end in bills....I am confused.

Comment: Clearly says "I'm looking for the handful of customers IDs where there is not a BILLS folder following the 8 digit account number."

Comment: But will it always have another group of digits after the 8 or will there be random strings also

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer elsewhere and to avoid the XKCD DenverCoder9 meme...

My issue was that in Powershell * is the wildcard character, not %.

Comment: Im not sure how your script is getting the job done as I am getting entries where like " HOSTNAME c$ Docs PROD 10010009 BILLS"
Which is what you Clearly said " where there is not a BILLS folder following the 8 digit account number"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your above data this

```
$list -split "`r?`n" | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=\\)\d{8}(?!\\BILLS)'|
  ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[0].Value} | 
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

Returns:

```
10010006
10010009
10010011
10010013
10010014
```

By using a regular expression with a [nonconsuming positive look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=\\)`and
a negative look ahead `(?!\\BILLS)`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your **primary problem was mistakenly using `%` rather than `*`** as the match-any-sequence-of-characters-including-none wildcard metacharacter.

However, there are **other things worth improving**:

- With large files, don't use `$list = Get-Content "sample.txt"` to read the array of lines into memory *at once* - instead, use PowerShell's *pipeline* to process the lines *one by one*, by piping to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.
- Don't use `Write-Host` to output *results*; doing so writes just to the *console*, and you won't be able to capture the data for later processing; instead, use `Write-Output` or, preferably, use implicit output.
- You don't strictly need a *wildcard expression* match the `BILLS` path component - all you need is to *trim trailing spaces from the end* before using *literal* string comparison with `'BILLS'`.

To put it all together:

```
Get-Content sample.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $parts = $_ -split '\\'
  if ($parts[7].TrimEnd() -ne 'BILLS') { $parts[6] }
}
```

`$parts[6]` is the account number - note that by not assigning it to a variable or redirecting it elsewhere it is *implicitly output*, so that the loop returns just the account numbers, as requested.

---

The above is memory-efficient, but potentially *slow*.
If that is a problem, read the lines using the .NET Framework directly.

```
[IO.File]::ReadLines("$PWD/sample.txt") | ForEach-Object {
  $parts = $_ -split '\\'
  if ($parts[7].TrimEnd() -ne 'BILLS') { $parts[6] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so what you can do is use some regex. 
Goal is to get all lines that dont have the Bills name after 8 digits

```
Get-Content "C:\Test\Fast Build\Bills_Test.txt" | ?{$_ -notmatch "[0-9]{8}.BILLS"}
```

Lets go over whats going on here

We **get-content** of the file, We then pipe **|** line by line the output to a **Where-Object** the alias being **?**. We then make sure using a -notmatch operator (Match in powershell checks aginst Regex, Like checks aginst wildcards).
In the regex we are looking for everything that doesnt have 8 Digits and **[0-9]{8}** and wildcard **.** with **BILLS**.